# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-studio

вылетает при запуске андроид приложения, как и где исправить? простите я просто чайник

cat_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/floppa"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Draw2D

```
package com.example.simplepaint1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;

public class Draw2D extends View {

    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private Rect mRect = new Rect();
    private Bitmap mBitmap;

    public Draw2D(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Выводим значок из ресурсов
        Resources res = this.getResources();
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.cat_bottom);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int width = canvas.getWidth();
        int height = canvas.getHeight();

        // стиль Заливка
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        // закрашиваем холст белым цветом
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawPaint(mPaint);

        // Рисуем жёлтый круг
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        // canvas.drawCircle(950, 30, 25, mPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(width - 90, 90, 125, mPaint);

        // Рисуем зелёный прямоугольник
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        //  canvas.drawRect(20, 650, 950, 680, mPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(0, canvas.getHeight() - 90, width, height, mPaint);

        // Рисуем текст
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setTextSize(47);
        //  canvas.drawText("Лужайка только для котов", 30, 648, mPaint);
        canvas.drawText("Лужайка только для котов", 90, height - 92, mPaint);

        // Текст под углом
        // int x = 810;
        int x = width - 320;
        int y = 340;

        mPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        mPaint.setTextSize(47);
        String beam = "Лучик солнца!";

        canvas.save();
        // Создаём ограничивающий прямоугольник для наклонного текста
        // поворачиваем холст по центру текста
        canvas.rotate(-45, x + mRect.exactCenterX(), y + mRect.exactCenterY());
        //canvas.rotate(+45, x + mRect.exactCenterX(), y + mRect.exactCenterY());
        // Рисуем текст
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawText(beam, x, y, mPaint);

        // восстанавливаем холст
        canvas.restore();

        // Выводим изображение
        // canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 450, 530, mPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, width - mBitmap.getWidth(), height - mBitmap.getHeight() - 10, mPaint);
    }
}
```

main_activity

```
package com.example.simplepaint1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Draw2D draw2D = new Draw2D(this);
        setContentView(draw2D);
    }
}
```

как исправить это?помогите

logcat

```
2022-05-20 19:22:54.747 21403-21403/? I/le.simplepaint: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2022-05-20 19:22:54.769 21403-21403/? I/le.simplepaint: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2022-05-20 19:22:54.771 21403-21403/? W/le.simplepaint: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2022-05-20 19:22:54.949 21403-21403/com.example.simplepaint1 D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-05-20 19:22:54.949 21403-21403/com.example.simplepaint1 D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-05-20 19:22:55.020 21403-21435/com.example.simplepaint1 D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2022-05-20 19:22:55.028 21403-21435/com.example.simplepaint1 D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2022-05-20 19:22:55.030 21403-21435/com.example.simplepaint1 D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2022-05-20 19:22:55.095 21403-21403/com.example.simplepaint1 D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
2022-05-20 19:22:55.153 21403-21403/com.example.simplepaint1 W/le.simplepaint: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-05-20 19:22:55.153 21403-21403/com.example.simplepaint1 W/le.simplepaint: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-05-20 19:22:55.200 21403-21433/com.example.simplepaint1 D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe9ff53e0, tid 21433
2022-05-20 19:22:55.203 21403-21433/com.example.simplepaint1 D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2022-05-20 19:22:55.204 21403-21433/com.example.simplepaint1 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2022-05-20 19:22:55.211 21403-21433/com.example.simplepaint1 D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe9ffb030: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2022-05-20 19:22:55.236 21403-21433/com.example.simplepaint1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe9ffb030: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xea33c450) (first time)
2022-05-20 19:22:55.245 21403-21433/com.example.simplepaint1 I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2022-05-20 19:22:55.245 21403-21433/com.example.simplepaint1 D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2022-05-20 19:22:55.245 21403-21433/com.example.simplepaint1 D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe9ffb2d0, tid 21433
2022-05-20 19:22:55.246 21403-21433/com.example.simplepaint1 D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2022-05-20 19:22:55.246 21403-21433/com.example.simplepaint1 D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3efffe000 size 0x2000
2022-05-20 19:22:55.273 21403-21433/com.example.simplepaint1 D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2022-05-20 19:22:55.279 21403-21403/com.example.simplepaint1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2022-05-20 19:22:55.280 21403-21403/com.example.simplepaint1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.simplepaint1, PID: 21403
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.simplepaint1.Draw2D.onDraw(Draw2D.java:83)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22350)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:806)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:559)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:565)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4101)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3099)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А чего непонятно? У вас объекта не существует. Поэтому и ошибка